# How do I represent XML as classes when it has multiple elements of same name

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

Assuming we have the following xml.

```
<Company>
  <Tables>
    <Agri>
      <Tables>
        <Table Id="1">
        </Table>
      </Tables>
      <Tables>
        <Table Id="2">
        </Table>
      </Tables>
    </Agri>
    <Tables>
      <Table Id="3">
      </Table>
    </Tables>
    <Tables>
      <Table Id="4">
      </Table>
    </Tables>
  </Tables>
</Company>
```

How do I represent such xml into classes?

I've tried something like this but doesn't seem to work.

```
void Test()
{
    string xml = //...
    using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        var company = (Company)new XmlSerializer(typeof(Company)).Deserialize(reader);
    }
}

public class Company
{
    public CompanyTables Tables { get; set; }
}
public class CompanyTables
{
    [XmlArray]
    public Table[] Tables { get; set; }
}
public class Table
{
    [XmlAttribute("Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what I can get so far.

[image]

I was thinking it would populate the `CompanyTable.Tables` with two `Table` instances (`Id` 3 and 4).

I'm ignoring the `Agri` element for now and just shown here to better reflect the actual structure of the xml.

I'll keep trying but any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: _but doesn't seem to work._ - can you elaborate what not working, how you check it is not working...

Comment: @Fabio please see updated question.

Answer (score 1):

`Table` class is wrapped within `Tables` class. So your `Tables` class should have "internal" collection of itself(`Tables`)

```
public class Company
{
    public List<Tables> Tables { get; set; }
}

// As you said Agri type ignored for now
public class Tables
{
    public Table Table { get; set; } // Use collection if Table can be more the one

    [XmlElement("Tables")]
    public Tables InnerTables { get; set; }
}

public class Table
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Test

```
private T DeserialzeFrom<T>(string xml)
{
    using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        return (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(reader);
    }
}

[Test]
public void ShouldDeserializeCompany()
{
    var xml = // Build xml string;

    // Expected deserialized object
    var expected = new Company
    {
        Tables = new List<Tables>
        {
            new Tables { Table = new Table { Id = "3" }},
            new Tables { Table = new Table { Id = "4" }}
        }
    };

    var actual = DeserialzeFrom<Company>(xml);

    actual.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expected); // Test passing
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I like your answer since it's much cleaner. But how will we add the `Agri` property to this? I'm trying it too btw :)

Comment: @PaoloGo, follow same pattern, looks like `Agri` have partially similar structure to the tables...

Comment: I posted my own answer. Could you please check if this is what you also have in mind to include `Agri`?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the class structure you require. With this structure I have serialised the data resulting in a matching XML output. Deserialising your xml above works too.

```
public class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        this.Tables = new CompanyTables();
    }

    [XmlElement]
    public CompanyTables Tables { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyTables
{
    public CompanyTables()
    {
        this.Agri = new Agri();
    }

    [XmlElement]
    public TablesArr[] Tables { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public Agri Agri { get; set; }
}

public class Agri
{
    public Agri() { }

    [XmlElementAttribute("Tables")]
    public TablesArr[] Tables { get; set; }
}

public class TablesArr
{
    public TablesArr() { }

    [XmlElementAttribute("Table")]
    public Table[] Tables { get; set; }
}

public class Table
{
    public Table() { }

    [XmlAttribute("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Serialise test:

```
string xml = "<Company><Tables><Agri><Tables><Table Id=\"1\"></Table></Tables><Tables><Table Id=\"2\"></Table></Tables></Agri><Tables><Table Id=\"3\"></Table></Tables><Tables><Table Id=\"4\"></Table></Tables></Tables></Company>";

XmlSerializer sx = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Company));

Company company = null;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    ms.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml).Length);

    ms.Flush();

    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    company = (Company)sx.Deserialize(ms);
}
```

Deserialise Test:

```
Company company = new TestBed.Company();

company.Tables.Agri.Tables = new TablesArr[2];
company.Tables.Agri.Tables[0] = new TablesArr();
company.Tables.Agri.Tables[0].Tables = new Table[1];
company.Tables.Agri.Tables[0].Tables[0] = new Table() { Id=1 };
company.Tables.Agri.Tables[1] = new TablesArr();
company.Tables.Agri.Tables[1].Tables = new Table[1];
company.Tables.Agri.Tables[1].Tables[0] = new Table() { Id=2 };

company.Tables.Tables = new TablesArr[2];
company.Tables.Tables[0] = new TablesArr();
company.Tables.Tables[0].Tables = new Table[1];
company.Tables.Tables[0].Tables[0] = new TestBed.Table() { Id=3 };

company.Tables.Tables[1] = new TablesArr();
company.Tables.Tables[1].Tables = new Table[1];
company.Tables.Tables[1].Tables[0] = new TestBed.Table() { Id=4 };


XmlSerializer sx = new XmlSerializer(company.GetType());

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    sx.Serialize(ms, company);

    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got to include `Agri` based on @Fabio's answer.

```
public class Company
{
    public CompanyTables Tables { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyTables
{
    [XmlElement]
    public List<Tables> Tables { get; set; }

    public List<Tables> Agri { get; set; }
}

public class Tables
{
    [XmlElement]
    public List<Table> Table { get; set; }
}

public class Table
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```